# How to open the Steam overlay if my controller doesn't have the guide button?

Tags: steam, controllers

My bluetooth controller emulates an xbox 360 controller, but, even if it reports 16 buttons, it actually has 15 buttons. It doesn't have the home button.

There's a way to map a different key combination to open the overlay?

Also: looks like the maker of my controller cheaped out a little bit with electronics, so start+select can't be pressed at the same time (if you press one, the other will be depressed)

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'Steam' > 'Settings', and from there to the 'In-Game' tab.
There's an '*Overlay shortcut keys*' box, where you can change the key-binding to anything you like:

[image: Steam's In-Game settings]

In 'Settings', there's also a tab dedicated to Controller settings:

[image: Steam's Controller settings]

Because I don't have a controller to test this out, I can't see whether or not there is an option there to change the controller keybinding for the Steam Overlay, but the [possibilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=steam%20controller%20settings&newwindow=1&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch) seem quite extensive anyway.

[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/234427/how-to-remap-buttons-on-your-steam-controller/)'s an in-depth guide on How-To-Geek.

Comment: i can change the shortcut for the keyboard, but for the controller, it's locked on the guide button...